# Concurrent two-way map in java

Tags: java, concurrency, hashmap, concurrenthashmap

I am writing code for text processing, and things go **a lot** faster if I convert the strings to integers first.  To do this I made a Dictionary class, where every time I see a new string, I give it an index, and keep two maps, one from string to int, and one from int to string, so I can easily look up both ways.  Here's the code:

```
class Dictionary {
    private Map<String, Integer> map;
    private Map<Integer, String> reverse_map;
    private int nextIndex;

    public Dictionary() {
        map = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
        reverse_map = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
        nextIndex = 1;
    }

    public int getIndex(String string) {
        if (!map.containsKey(string)) {
            map.put(string, nextIndex);
            reverse_map.put(nextIndex, string);
            nextIndex++;
        }
        return map.get(string);
    }

    public String getString(int index) {
        // getIndex is always called first, so we don't need to check anything
        return reverse_map.get(index);
    }
}
```

This has been working fine for me in my single-threaded code.  But now I want to give this multiple threads to speed it up more, and I'm not sure how to do it.  I thought of using ConcurrentHashMap, but I'm not sure that `putIfAbsent` will guarantee that I don't use an index twice.  I didn't want to use Collections.synchronizedMap, because this dictionary is accessed really frequently across the threads and so I probably wouldn't be much better off than with a single thread, because it blocks on every read and write.  Is there a way to make this work?

Comment: hmm, so you need only insert/get and the key is self generated (i.e. incremental?), if so the algorithm can be made faster that the same above even concurrently

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest thing is to just label your two methods (`getIndex` and `getString`) `synchronized`.  See what kind of speedup you get.  Maybe it will be enough.

To use `ConcurrentHashMap`, you might try this:

```
private AtomicInteger nextIndex;
public int getIndex(String string) {
    Integer n = map.get(string);
    if (n == null) {
        int idx = nextIndex.getAndIncrement();
        n = map.putIfAbsent(string, idx);
        if (n != null) return n;
        reverse_map.put(idx, string);
        return idx;
    }
    return n;
}
```

This may occasionally skip an index if two threads insert the same string at the same time, but it won't be often.

Comment: This looks like it'll work.  I didn't know about `getAndIncrement` from `AtomicInteger`, and I was worried about possibly using the same index to refer to two different strings on accident.  If I always `getAndIncrement`, I might skip indexes, like you say, but never have duplicate indexes, which would be really bad.  Thanks!

Comment: `n` is almost guaranteed to be `null` at the time you're using it as the key in the second map. `putIfAbsent` returns the previous value under the key, which you have just checked to be `null`.

Comment: Right, if `n == null`, use `idx` as the key in `reverse_map`, else use `n`.

Comment: @mattg Actually (see my solution), else **don't use anything** -- skip that step.

Answer (score 2):

Your issue with a concurrent solution is atomicity. These are my thoughts:

```
private final ConcurrentMap<String, Integer> map = new ConcurrentHashMap<String, Integer>();
private final ConcurrentMap<Integer, String> reverse_map = new ConcurrentHashMap<Integer, String>();
private final AtomicInteger nextIndex = new AtomicInteger(1);

public int getIndex(String string) {
  Integer i = map.get(string);
  if (i == null) {
    final Integer newI = nextIndex.getAndIncrement();
    i = map.putIfAbsent(string, newI);
    if (i == null) {
      reverse_map.put(newI, string);
      return newI;
    }
  }
  return i;
}
```

This has a very benign failure mode: some indices will be left unused.

Notice that I put to the second map unconditionally since at this point I know I'm in charge for the string at hand.

Comment: CHM uses locks too, I'd says it's possible to do non-lock-reader 2way map. Never need it and it's not interesting enough to try doing.

Comment: I think the only part that really needs to be atomic is the first insert; the second one is just a duplication, and if I can guarantee that I get the right result back from `putIfAbsent` on the first one, things should be alright.  My problem is the interplay between `nextIndex++` and `map.putIfAbsent`.  You can probably do it, I just don't know enough about threaded programming to be sure to get it right.

Comment: @bestsss Doesn't CHM lock only on writes?

Comment: @mattg I see, I missed that part. `putIfAbsent` returns the previous value under the key so if it returns a non-null value, you know that some other thread is already ahead of you dealing with the string. In that case just skip the second step. I think that may be it, but would have to think it through a bit more.

Comment: Sure, yes on writes only the new CHM v8.x is actually even better, Cliff Click's version of concurrent hashtable is totally lock-free